# Custom index or unique constraint

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to store urls in an index but I want unique url.

I'm making POST request to store my documents but I want to avoid duplicate document based on the url field.

Is there a way to specify a unique constraint on the url field ?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know, but you can use your url as the document ID instead, that would make it effectively unique.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy you need to adopt here would be to create a unique key per document. In your case choose the URL as the document ID.

Taking checksum using sha1 or similar algorithm will do the job for getting the unique key for the URL, in case URL is long. Make this the document ID so that only one page occurs at all point of time. Again use _create API to index if you don't want new duplicates to be indexed (More efficient), and in case you want the new ones to be the document use normal indexing.

In case you need to modify the original document in case of discovery of duplicate document, use upser.

I have gone to a great deal of this topic in this [blog](https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two-step solution to *index* only unique values:

1. You could use the [Unique Tokenfilter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/unique-tokenfilter/) on the url field to store only unique urls:

   ```
   {
   "settings": {
       "analysis": {
           "analyzer": {
               "uniqueTokenfilter": {
                   "type": "custom",
                   "tokenizer": "keyword",
                   "filter": "unique"
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "mappings": {
       "index" : {
           "properties": {
               "url": {
                   "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "unique"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
   ```
2. Then, you could perform a Scroll Term Query to return only documents with unique urls. You could direct these returned documents to a separate index, creating an index with only unique urls.

   ```
   curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/doc/_search?scroll=5m -d '{
      "query": {
          "term" : "url"
       }
   }'
   ```

**What you may want instead is to index all docs, but *query* for only unique field values. This is known as [grouping/field collapsing](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256) and is not currently supported in Elasticsearch.